# TFS 2012 Branch merge doesnt get everything

Tags: tfs

So Im trying to merge from branch A to B and after doing the merge, I check in the changes to B and then compare the branches again.  There are still differences detected.  One of which is a entity data model diagram "my_model.edmx.diagram".

Looking at the differences, its only seeing a difference in the location and width of the entity icons etc.  This file is really just an xml file.  There was also a .sql file also that didnt get merged and I managed to get it merged over by selecting it byitself, then merging just that file.  The edmx.diagram file however, will not go over.  Could it be an issue of file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard this file type issue. If you can put the files into source control. Suppose these files must be supported by TFS.

A workaroud for this situation:

1. Clean the mapping folder for branch B(Make sure changes checked in)
   and remove the mapping of branch B.
2. Remapping it to a clear local folder.
3. Merge branchA to B again, and check in the changes.

---

Update

> Changes in each branch are independent from each other, so you don’t
>   have to check them in before switching from one branch to another.
>   **Merging between sibling branches requires a baseless merging.**
>
> Source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/code/overview  (Capabilities→ Fundamentals → Branching  )

Comment: Ok, tried this also.  No dice!  Cleaned the target folder, remapped and did the merge again - this time the response was "There were no changes to merge".  Yet, if I go back in SCE (source control explorer) and to a compare at the branch level, I still see 3 files as different.

Comment: Maybe I need to do a baseless merge?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx

Comment: Well well well....the baseless merge did the trick.  The question now is...why did that become necessary?

Comment: Also, when I did the baseless merge, every single file in the solution was marked as changed and listed in the pending changes during check in.    Reviewing the docs a bit on using a baseless merge, Im not sure it was really necessary.  Both branches were created from an original single branch.  Well, since the source & target in question are not related in a parent/child structure, then maybe this is in deed whats needed.   We started from a single branch and created 3 branches (development, staging and release)

Comment: Did anyone do a merge discard? Are the changes that were missed to do with the same changeset? Or same user?

Comment: No, I was the only one doing a merge.

Comment: @BitShift This is the reason. Usually not recommend to merge in this way. Please see my reply in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using source control instead of Team Explorer. I had the same problem.

Asif